# Pushing a copy of the database to a server

Tags: mongodb, web-deployment

I'm making a website, and the amount of hard-coded data is getting out of hand, so I want to move it to a database.

I've considered using MongoDB to do this.

What I want to know is whether or not I can push a local database to my server without manually needing to re-create the data.

The way I like to work, is I make changes on my local machine, and then once everything works I push it to the server, I want to do the exact same with my database. I haven't found any information regarding how to do it or if it's even possible.

Any help?

Comment: Create scripts that load the right data, once the data loads right in dev, run the script against your prod db

Comment: @tymeJV and what happens if I run the same script twice? wouldn't I end up with duplicate data?

Comment: Probably - have a revert script handy as well - so when you need to make changes in dev, just wipe the existing data, load the new data.

Comment: Ever thought of using an scm tool for this? Example workflow for git([flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)): Merge your new stuff from a feature branch into "develop", check "develop" out to a test server, do your tests and if it passes, create a new release (which will merge your changes into "master", tagging the corresponding revision. Check out the release to your production environment. Mission accomplished. Using DBs to store static data is so 90s.

Answer (score 0):

This is what database migration tools are here for. With relational databases flyway is quite a nice piece of software.

The basic concept is that for every data modification you create a migration script (typically a SQL file). The migration tool will then keep track of which migrations have already been executed and which need to be done.

Unfortunately I can't give you any good tool for mongodb. A short Googling found this here. It might not be the best choice but it should show the intention

https://github.com/emirotin/mongodb-migrations